# Cannot access samba share on Android Device

Tags: networking, permissions, samba, android

I'm trying to access my samba share on my android device using es file explorer, but I receive the following message - "Login Fails: This may be caused by: - The account has no permissions." (I think it's logged in as a guest user as I was able to access test shares set to 777)

I've been able to access the shares before but today it appears I've been shut out. I'm able to access the shares from my windows machines without any difficulty.

The share is setup to prompt for a password for user login, but I'm not receiving any prompt when I access it using es file explorer. Is there any way I can force the program to bring up a log in prompt?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem here.
You need to install both GUI for managing samba shares and users and the package gksu.
After that, open the GUI SAMBA and add your user to the list of users with permission to the directory.

Comment: Can you please explain more in detail, how to install this management software and use it? At the moment, I feel, your question is missing some crucial point.